# I noticed that my terminals get a bit kooky after they forcibly disconnect from SSH

Tags: shell, ssh, terminal, focus

The terminal begins to behave a little bit strangely after an SSH session inside has been terminated (due to sleeping the computer or killing it via `<Enter>+~+.`).

It causes a beep to be emitted whenever focus enters and leaves the particular terminal. Also when in my zsh shell, a blank new line appears to be fed into the terminal.

I've tested this in:

- tmux in alacritty
- raw alacritty
- iTerm2

This is not a hugely annoying behavior, although the bell is definitely annoying for sure.

Today I was able to finally find a way to reproduce the behavior. Clearly this is somehow related to a terminal mode that SSH puts the terminal into and which it fails to clean up when it dies. But it is also related to the focus reporting.

I have tried `stty sane` but it does not work. Not even starting and quitting vim works. That usually is able to reset various other terminal state weirdnesses, such as being stuck in mouse mode where clicking the mouse on the terminal (and especially scrolling your mouse) produces lots of bells.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the answer https://superuser.com/a/1017817/98199, I found that issuing the command `echo '\x1b[?1004l'` does effectively turn off the focus reporting, and restores normal behavior.

Since vim definitely is capable of recognizing focus events I do not know why starting and stopping vim does not do the trick for this. I suppose I will make this command into an alias and just run it when I need to.